# How to use node_modules directory from some other node project

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a thought. Lets say I am learning angular and I create many test projects. With the command `ng new project_name`  . Each time I fire this command it takes hell lot of time to download and install node_modules. What I am thinking can I create project with `ng new project_name --skip-install` to create project and skip the node module installation and later on I refer in my project configuration file (systemjs.config.js)

```
paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'  <-- here I change the path to some other directory
    },
```

to use node_modules directory from some other previous project that already have module installed. What I am try to achieve is not to download same module again and again and also not to slow down my project creation time.

Comment: You could use the package manager `pnpm` to achieve this. https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm

Comment: I did experiment with several tools. Easy solution would be to create app with no module install and then create a symbolic link.                                 1. For window  mklink /D node_modules  location\node_modules                                       
2. For Linux ln -s target and source